# Error in running Scala Program: Main method not found in class main, please define the main method

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I am totally new in Scala. What I have done is that , I have installed **Scala 2.13.6**,**SBT 1.5.5** and **Intellij 2021.2**  on Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed plugin scala and sbt executor in Intellij. When I create a new Scala class and write this code to it, I can run that without any errors:

```
object main extends App{
    println("Hello")
}
```

But when I have this code, I cannot run it:

```
class exm {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit={
    println("Hello world")
      }
}
```

The error is in the following:

```
Error: Main method is not static in class exm, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)
```

I know that IDE think the code is Java, but why?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: the static methods in Scala go into the companion object of a class, not in itself. So you have to define a `class exm` and put whatever you want to in it. Then in the  same file, also define an `object exm` and put your main method in there.

Comment: Dear @James thank you for your feedback. I add ```object exm``` and the end of the file after class definition, but still I receive error.

Comment: @M_Gh You should update your question so that it corresponds to the current code you have after you used James' advice. Also provide current error.

Comment: @M_Gh have you written `object exm extends App` or just `object exm`? The former is wrong. Either you extend from `App` or you put the `main` method in there. you should not be doing both.

Comment: @James thank you. I did ```object exm extends App``` and it run without problem. But I wanted to know why I cannot run a simple scala class and receive that error. @ninpin's answer was the point that I need.

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main function needs to be inside an object, not a class definition. So instead of this

```scala
package main_function_test

class exm {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello world")
  }
}
```

write this:

```scala
package main_function_test

object exm {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello world")
  }
}
```